# 304 Not Modified message showing when try to parse a json file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            console.log(getJ());
            function getJ() {
                $.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        console.log(key);

                    });
                });

            }

        });
```

Above one my HTML code and below one my json.json file's code

```
{
    "message": {
        "success":"Information inserted successfully.",
        "update":"Information updated successfully.",
        "delete":"Information deleted successfully.",
    },
    "Jennifer": {
        "status":"Active"
    },
    "James": {
        "status":"Active",
        "age":56,
        "count":10,
        "progress":0.0029857,
        "bad":0
    }
}
```

when I try to parse this bunch of code it show 304 message and i don't get any required results.

Comment: It means that the result of your parsing has been cached

Comment: How to solve this issue.

Comment: ok I find my solution. in the line "delete":"Information deleted successfully." there is a extra comma(,) that causes my problem and it shows the 304 message.

Comment: So please post it as an answer and mark as solved

Comment: I have no enough reputation to post an answer. I tried it but unable to post answer.

Answer (score 0):

since your JSON is not in array.. you  don't need to use `$.each`.. get it directly with `.`

here

```
  $.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {

                console.log(data.message.success); //show Information inserted successfully.
                console.log(data.Jennifer.status); //Active
            });
```

Comment: not sure if you mean with _don't have to use_ that it won't work or that you need not to use `each`. so i just want to mention that `jQuery.each` works for both _objects_ and _arrays_.

Comment: i mean to say .. you can get your respective json object directly with `.` operator without using the `each` function.. since his json object not in array.. i think getting it directly is better...:):).. anyways updating my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could make the url unique:

```
$.getJSON('json.json?_=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        console.log(key);
    });
});
```

Or use `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```